# Is spark RDD.fold method buggy?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I found that spark RDD.fold and scala List.fold behave differently with same input.

Scala 2.11.8

```
List(1, 2, 3, 4).fold(1)(_ + _) // res0: Int = 11
```

I think this is correct output because 1 + (1 + 2 + 3 + 4) equals 11. But spark RDD.fold looks buggy.

Spark 2.0.1(not clustered)

```
sc.parallelize(List(1, 2, 3, 4)).fold(1)(_ + _) // res0: Int = 15
```

Although RDD is not a simple collection, this result does not make sense. Is this a known bug or normal result?

Comment: @Shankar thanks! I should have searched more before this question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not buggy, you're just not using in the right way. `zeroElement` should be neutral, it means that it has to satisfy following condition:

```
op(x, zeroValue) === op(zeroValue, x) === x
```

If `op` is `+` then the right choice is 0.

Why restriction like this? If `fold` is to be executed in parallel each chunk will have to initialize its own `zeroValue`. In a more formal way you can think about `Monoid` where:

- `op` is equivalent to • (this is a simplification, in practice `op` in Spark should be commutative, not only associative).
- `zeroElement` is equivalent to identity element.